# Post data and retrieve the response using PHP Curl?

Tags: php, post, curl, webservice-client

I'm very new to working with web services, and so I'm finding this pretty confusing.

If I have a URL I'm trying to post some JSON data to, I understand how to do this using the CURL PHP method.

What I'm wondering is, if I do this, and the URL has some kind of server response.. how do I get that response in my php and use it to take different actions within the PHP accordingly?

Thanks!

-Elliot

Comment: Can you show some of the code you have right now?

Comment: This answer here worked for me [https://stackoverflow.com/a/34933064/4601322](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34933064/4601322)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You'll have to set the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option to true.

```
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

The response to your request will be available in the $result variable.

Answer (score 8):

If you are referring to different actions for different HTTP response codes, then you can do something like:

```
$response = curl_exec($req);
$responseInfo = curl_getinfo($req);

$httpResponseCode = $responseInfo['http_code'];
```

Answer (score 6):

The default behavior of Curl is to just dump the data you get back out to the browser. In order to instead capture it to a variable, you need:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$txResult = curl_exec($ch);
```

Also you can use [parse_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) on this $txResult to properly format it.