# Post request using CURL

Tags: php, ajax, post, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post data and retrieve the response using PHP Curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947025/post-data-and-retrieve-the-response-using-php-curl)

I want to make a number of POST requests (about 1000) to read data from a webpage which accepts post requests.I am aware about the implementing CURL through GET, but not through POST. So, please help me in this.

Thanks in advance...:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)? Basically, just do a curl_setopt()

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST);
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everyone else, quick search through the docs would have helped you here.

Heres an explination I found on how to do it http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use curl_setopt to set the CURLOPT_POST option to TRUE like this:

```
$curl_request = curl_init('http://path/to/url');
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
// Finish setting options and make the request
```