# Getting data from a website where posted data is required

Tags: php, html-parsing

I am new at php, so bear with me.

I want to parse some html-data from a website, and i can do it with http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ pretty easy. The problem is that i need to get the data from a website, where i need to post some data, which means i can't just use the url which the library needs. I can use the action and post i a form to redirect to the website, but i can't get the information. Can you help me here?

Regards
Jesper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code **queries stackoverflow for your question** using [CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947025/post-data-and-retrieve-the-response-using-php-curl):

```
$url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/search';

$params = preparePostFields( array(
     'q' => 'Getting data from a website where posted data is required',
   ));

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;

exit;

function preparePostFields($array) {
  $params = array();

  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $params[] = $key . '=' . urlencode($value);
  }

  return implode('&', $params);
}
```

Regarding the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, please review this [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

Comment: I tried that, but when i echo my $result it says "Missing parameter". The website only use one form, with name=aarskort and my $params is:
$params = array('aarskort' => '20113670');
You know why?

Comment: Post the form's definition to provide more details.

Comment: <FORM action="./ElevSkema.asp" method="post">
        Opslag for mine tilmeldinger - Indtast årskortnr
        <INPUT style="WIDTH: 102px; HEIGHT: 22px" size=15 name=aarskort>
        <INPUT type=submit value=Søg name=B1>
    </FORM>

Comment: You probably need to set B1 too, since the form-handler might check its value too.

Comment: Ehm, how? :) In the $params-array?

Comment: @gedemagt Fixed my post to be an complete working example. Additionally: Could you disclose the actual form's URL, you'd like to get data from?